# Don't tell me which of my credentials is wrong

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, login, security, authentication

If I mistype my username or password when logging in to Stack Exchange, the red dialogue box tells me *which* was incorrect.

If an attacker correctly guesses an email address present in the database and submits a bad password, the dialogue helpfully informs them  they've typed an existing email address, but that the *password* is incorrect.

References as to why this is a bad thing, from Sec.SE:

- [Why is it common to only say “username or password is incorrect” in case of login errors?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44870/89737)
- [“Username and/or Password Invalid” - Why do websites show this kind of message instead of informing the user which one was wrong?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17820/89737)
- [Disclose to user if account exists?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40694/disclose-to-user-if-account-exists)

Can we fix this security bug, or at least have an explanation why it won't be fixed?

---

Yes, this is a similar question to [Don't give away incorrect password/username info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147938/dont-give-away-incorrect-password-username-info), but that question is merely seeking discussion.

It does not have an accepted answer, no employees or Community Mods took notice, and it's tagged with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), not [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Moreover, it doesn't have [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) / [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) / [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) / [status-anything-else](/questions/tagged/status-anything-else) so that question does not fulfill this bug report.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147938/dont-give-away-incorrect-password-username-info (since it's only a discussion asking for opinions, not marking as duplicate)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just updated my question

Comment: It's a dupe of the title, but the actual question there is only asking for opinions.

Comment: Note that the answers on "Disclose to user if account exists?" don't really say "this is a bad thing" -- the top answer says this was done for historical reasons that no longer really apply (and *really* doing this right requires you to build your sign-up UX flow so it doesn't reveal if an email is already in use at sign-up time), and the second answer says this is largely important for websites for which membership might be embarrassing, which doesn't really apply for most (all?) SE sites.

Comment: Quite probably related: [The God Login](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-god-login/) by Jeff Atwood. The reasoning for actually telling the user they entered a correct e-mail is outlined there. I'm not sure if that's still the de-facto reasoning, but I daresay it's at least close

Comment: Can we add feature-request to the tags?

Comment: @DnrDevil I'm considering this a security bug; it's kind of weird to file it as both a feature-request and a bug

Comment: @tac still, by marking as feature request you imply "OK, I know this is the current design, but I want you (the SE team) to change it".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've asked internally, and it seems that this is currently "by design" rather than accidental, and that *initially* it was implemented the way you would prefer. As such, it is trying to strike a balance between usability (people fat-finger their details very often) and absolute security. We are familiar with the pros and cons of both, however. I have reopened that discussion.

Comment: Aww, okay, if you *insist*. :(

Comment: [tag:status-review] then, or [tag:status-bydesign]? (or declined)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm going to mark it by design, but bring it up in our next Monday meeting... which will actually be on a Tuesday because of UK holidays, but it will still be the Monday meeting, because reasons

Comment: Thanks. While personally  I don't think it's critical issue, all other sites I know (well, major sites at least) act in the different way OP is requesting which is not telling the exact reason of login failure, just saying "email or password incorrect" so I would expect SE to follow. That said, SE is special in many ways, this can be yet another way. :)